# Audit log (trail) tampering in databases

Tags: database, auditing, tampering

Lets say we have a application which has a database - MySQL, SQL Server, or Oracle, for example. 
And let's assume that we have multiple people, like db and audit administrators, who have admin access privileges to the database. Let's say one of the people modifies a record and change the audit trail(since they have admin privileges I think they could do anything to the database, but correct me if I am wrong).

Is there any other way to detect this? Since changing the audit trail will cover up the tampering of the database record.

Do any of the database vendors has a solution for this? I guess this goes under the audit log tampering detection under the Database Forensics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the database is sufficiently important to mandate an audit, it will probably also have a backup schedule.

One possible way (i may be wrong) would be to compare the suspect database against the backup dump; this may not be feasible if the admin/audit users are also assigned backup privileges.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I want to know whether there are mechanisms use by database vendors to overcome this problem. Since the administrators have the super user privileges. So they have to use alternative function. [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/auditing.htm#autoId96) here under the "Auditing the Database Audit Trail" mentioned that privileged users can delete audit records. But that also recorded. But they haven't mentioned about the integrity of the data after such audit trial alteration.

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach is to get dedicated server at your company or rent a virtual server from a reliable supplier (like Amazon). Make sure that credentials for your app are different from credentials to the server. Whenever user deletes a record - backend should archive it instead. This makes it difficult to tamper the records.

Backup the database. You need backups in case someone breaks bd by mistake.

Use **hash chains**.